# Vue.js 3 JavaScript Objects members losing ref reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm updating a web app from using Knockout.js Templates to Vue 3 Components. This issue is not in the components but in the JS where I'm creating objects to be used in the components.

I'm running into strange behaviour around using refs where an object member is not always being set as a ref. I haven't been able to recreate this in an example but a simplified version of the structure is that we have an attribute that returns an object that contains the ref value.

```
function Attribute(val) {
  var value = ref(val);
  
  return {
    value: value
  }
}
```

We have a builder that is used to add labels and other items such permissions and classes to the UI.

```
function UIBuilder() {
  var self = this;
  var newElement = {};
  
  function newText(value) {
    newElement.inputType = 'TEXT';
    newElement.value = value;
    return self;
  }
  
  function addLabel(lbl) {
    newElement.label = lbl;
    return self;
  }
  
  function build() {
    return newElement;
  }  
  
  this.newText = newText;
  this.addLabel = addLabel;
  this.build = build;
}
```

Finally there is a function that returns an object that contains everything that the component needs.

```
function TextInput(initValue) {
  var self = this;
  self.label = initValue.label;
  self.value = initValue.value;
  
  var textInput = {
    label: self.label,
    value: self.value
  };
  
  return textInput;
}
```

Then I create an object to be passed to the component.

```
var attr = new Attribute(5225);
var textBox = new TextInput(new UIBuilder().newText(attr).addLabel('Description').build());
```

This structure works using Knockout and I'm trying to keep as much of the existing code as possible.

Most of the time this works but there are some occasions where the value is coming in as a string rather then a ref. I haven't been able to isolate why this is happening. While debugging most of the time the values for initValue.value and self.value look like this in the watch on VS Code.

[image: VS Code Watch Screenshot 1]

On some occasions it changes to string values even though the objects were created using the same functions.

[image: VS Code Watch Screenshot 2]

I checked the initValue object when taking the screenshot and it appeared to be a ref

[image: VS Code Screenshot 3]

As far as I can see the value should stay as a ref. I'm not unwrapping it in code. Why is this happening? What should I look for?

Comment: Hello, I've ran into similar problem. After adding class instance with `Ref` reactive array attribute to array of objects, the attribute loses the `.value` and the attribute appears like it's normal array, instead of reactive array. Have you found out what was the issue here @Tom ?